# How can I get password string back from the hash function used in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash, passwords

I am trying to implement **User friendly password system** where in if user enters the original password with one extra character, I want to tag it as valid login.

I am not using any library for generating hash, but, rather I've used this hash generator code:

Note : "password" has the password string. "hash" is the hash generated from it.

```
let p = 131, valM=Math.pow(10,9)+7
    for(let i=0;i<password.length;i++){
        let charCode = password.charCodeAt(i)
        //console.log(password[i],charCode)
        hash += charCode*(Math.pow(p,password.length-(i+1)))
    }
hash %= valM
```

Now I want to somehow get the password string "password" back from the hash value "hash".

**So my question is: how can I get the original password from the "hash" string?**

Thank you for any help that can be extended. Looking forward to expert guidance and support to understand this.

Comment: To best illustrate what you are asking:  Let's say we have a hash algorithm that simply adds two numbers together to get a resulting hash.  I tell you that the resulting hash value is 42.  You have no other information than the hash algorithm and the hash value of 42.  With only that information, there is no way to determine the two numbers added together to get 42...

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the password from the hash is impossible. The easiest way to see this is from the pigeonhole principle.

There are at most 2^64 possible values of hash, since numbers in JavaScript are IEEE doubles. However, there are far more than 2^64 possible passwords—in fact, there are infinitely many. There is thus no function that is surjective from the set of hashes, H, to the set of passwords, P. In other words, there is no function f from H to P such that each password p ∈ P, there is a hash h satisfying f(h) = p.